# Meaning Of [0] in array($productByCode[0]["code"]

Tags: php

I'm trying to understand some code from an online tutorial, and stumbled upon something I don't understand.

```
$productByCode = $db_handle->runQuery("SELECT * FROM tblproduct WHERE code='" . $_POST["code"] . "'");

$itemArray = array($productByCode[0]["code"]=>array('name'=>$productByCode[0]["name"], 
                                                    'code'=>$productByCode[0]["code"], 
                                                    'price'=>$productByCode[0]["price"]));
```

What does the `[0]` in `array($productByCode[0]["code"]`  mean?

Comment: Google "php nested arrays"

Answer (score 0):

It usually means 1st element. Indexes start from 0. So [0] means 1st element in that array. I see that you are fetching DB record set. It means 1st row in your case.

Comment: Adding little bit more, It means the `code` column's value of the first record fetched from the DB.